# Filtering a list without a loop

Tags: python, join

I have the following code in Python, which goes through two long dict, resulting in appending to a new list. The first dict contains a nested dicts

Example:

```
{'1234':{
          '3223':2,
          '2343':3
        },
 '2343': {
          '2332':3
          },
 .....}
```

The second dict, dataMov, contains unique values needed.

Below is the code I have:

```
    for item in data:
        list_Itemj=[]
        for user in dataMov[item]:
            list_Itemj.append(int(dataMov[item][user]))
```

Basically, how would I go about joining the two dictionaries and keeping the records where both the dictionaries have a value attached to it in Python. In SQL, I would use a 'JOIN'.

Comment: Based on the syntax what you have appear to be dictionaries. Could you post a complete, minimal example (including shortened lists) ?

Comment: Are you sure that you are using lists? They look like dictionaries to me - at least `data` is one.

Comment: Yes sorry its dictionaries not lists. I keep confusing the two.

Comment: Joining two dictionaries is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-can-i-merge-two-python-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression

Comment: @roadrunner66 Thank you